# Significato di “tranne poi”

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di «tranne poi» nella seguente frase?

> Basta a questi euroburocrati sempre pronti a cedere alle richieste americane, **tranne poi** ricevere lo stipendio dalle tasche del contribuente europeo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In questo caso la locuzione "tranne poi" viene utilizzata in forma avversativa col significato di  "però" o "tuttavia" e indica la contrapposizione polemica tra il fatto che *"questi euroburocrati"* sono sempre pronti a cedere alle richieste americane e che tuttavia poi (ovvero alla fine, in ultima analisi) sono pagati dai contribuenti europei (e dunque non dovrebbero comportarsi così).

Sarebbe equivalente a scrivere:

*"Questi euroburocrati (sono) sempre pronti a cedere alle richieste americane, **però alla fine ricevono** lo stipendio dalle tasche del contribuente europeo"*

L'espressione è una forma contratta (a mio avviso) di **"tranne per il fatto che poi..."**

Si potrebbe sostituire *"tranne poi"* con *"salvo poi"*.